# How to do simple state management with components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, state-management

Vue documentation gives an [example of simple state management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch), for a single-file app:

```
const sourceOfTruth = {}

const vmA = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})

const vmB = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})
```

**How to use the same mechanism for components?**

I tried to move this concept of a minimal state manager to components [in a codesandbox.io sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-darkness-mozij?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). It did not work and the more meaningful error, I believe, is

> The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

Does this mean that components must be completely standalone and cannot rely on data managed outside of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [Sandbox updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sinoussi-lbrvo)

in dataMaster.js

```
 var store = {
  state: {
    message: "Hello!"
  }
};

module.exports = store;
```

and component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{sharedState}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./dataMaster";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      privateState: {},
      sharedState: store.state
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: nice example with the private and shared state!!

Answer (score 1):

> The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions

It means that the `data` property you define in the component must be a function, and that function **should** return a **per-instance value**. You **should**, not any **must** here, and it can be tricked.

About the error, you got the error not because of state management, but because **you forgot to export the function in `dataMaster.js`**, so you couldn't import and use it in HelloWorld.vue. You got the error because you didn't **return a function**, that was the **function** part, not **per-instance** or anything related to state management.

To do the trick that I think you want, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-carson-l3oui. You change the same source of truth directly from components, yet without tools like VueX or something. But it's tricky and is exactly what the error try to avoid, **return a per-instance value**. I don't know what the advantages and disadvantages of it yet, but at the end of the day, I think to do state management, we should use the standard recommended way from the prior people, like VueX, etc, just choose one from tons of them.

```js
// dataMaster.js
const data = {
  msg: "hello From dataMaster"
};

export default function dataMaster() {
  return data // this is not "per-instance", they're the same across all instances
}

//Hello.vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{msg}}
    <button @click="change">Change</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import dataMaster from "./dataMaster.js";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data: dataMaster,
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.msg = this.msg === "message1" ? "message2" : "message1";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To address your last point, this method is suggested by Vue itself (in the docs I linked) and while `vuex` is the "industrial" solution, I wanted to check the simple one suggested in the docs - but in a components context.

Comment: @WoJ But the docs also says `We have a single source of truth now, but debugging would be a nightmare. Any piece of data could be changed by any part of our app at any time, without leaving a trace.` I think the example I give above is the working implementation of that method. It works, yet on small example, but would be a nightmare for debug in bigger projects.

Comment: @WoJ But the docs also says `We have a single source of truth now, but debugging would be a nightmare. Any piece of data could be changed by any part of our app at any time, without leaving a trace.` I think the snippet I give above is a working implementation of that method *in the components context*. It works, yet on small examples, but would be a nightmare for debugging in bigger projects. And to make it more reliable in big projects, you then will add something up, end up with a VueX yourself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"data" option should be a function, cause pure object could make data mess up. e.g when "sourceOfTruth" modified by componentA but you are focus on componentB, and you will confused. so please use "vuex" or "eventbus".

Comment: `data` is a function in the code I linked in my question. I am not sure I understand the second part of your answer: a modification in one component being reflected in another one is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have read your code in the sandbox,  and there is a error in your dataMaster.js. You should add 'export default ' in front of the dataMaster fn. like this:

`export default function dataMaster () {
  return {
    msg: 'hello from dataMaster'
  }
}`

Comment: as for `Does this mean that components must be completely standalone and cannot rely on data managed outside of them?`.
you can but should not make data mix in together, because a clear data flow is more important than less code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to manage all data from global state. you should search and learn Vuex and Store Management.

Maybe using "Event Bus" is better for you [example](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860).

And you're wrong with this code, we always need to export the code.
`export default function dataMaster() {
  return {
    msg: "hello from dataMaster"
  };
}`